# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: instance error in DevExpress Dashboard Designer in Asp.Net MVC5 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, dashboard

I want to create a Dashboard in Asp.Net MVC5 application using DevExpress. When I add DevExpress Dashboard it gives me the error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: instance".

I am using Devexpress v16.1.

Furthermore, I want to ask if there are better ways to do the same thing in Asp.Net MVC application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you migrate the project to your system? Often this is caused when migrating.

**Steps to try :**

> 1. Install Devexpress latest version if not installed. Reinstall if already installed. Upgrade if you're using an older version.
> 2. If you're using Devexpress dll's, remove and readd them.
> 3. Rebuild the entire solution.

Comment: I solved the error by degrading DevExpress to 15.2. I built a Dashboard, how can I display it in my application?

Comment: Display what in your application?

Comment: I added the DevExpress Dashboard. How can I view it?

Comment: The dashboard can be displayed by running your application.

Comment: Obviously.  I want to display it when I click a button.